# Linking to images from assets/img folder in bigcommerce stencil

Tags: bigcommerce

Im building a bigcommerce Stencil theme and I need a way to link to images in the `assets/img` folder... I tried the following...

`<img src="{{cdn "webdav:assets/img/logo-bug.svg"}}">` and `<img src="/assets/images/logo-bug.svg">` but neither worked in both after bundling and uploading the theme.

`http://***.mybigcommerce.com/assets/images/logo-bug.svg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Ive tried several other combinations but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

To call images inside your **theme's assets/img folder**, use the cdn handlebar helper below.

```
<img src="{{cdn 'img/filename.jpg'}}">
```

To call images inside your **webdav content folder**, use the cdn helper with a webdav prefix. *webdav file structure content/img/filename.jpg*

```
<img src="{{cdn "webdav:img/image.jpg"}}">
```

To call images inside your projects **assets/scss files**, use the following structure.

```
background: #fff url("../img/filename.jpg") no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload the image to /assets/images/ and link using the snippet below. Will work locally and once uploaded to the live site.

```
<img src="{{cdn '/assets/images/filename.png'}}">
```